# I want to achieve a transparent type carousal in bootstrap or angular material

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve a carousal type effect but on the entire page and with background page being kind of grayed like in modal.
Something like :

[image]

How can i achieve it , is there any plugin for it ? What framework to use ? it looks like it could be achieved with bootstrap carousel to me  but i want it to be applied to the entire screen and background should be grayed like in a dialog box. Not able to understand how to achieve it .
Any ideas/suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: it will be better if you will use bootstrap you can also modify CSS for a background to be grey. simple example link https://www.bootply.com/91532

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ This's is one of the best. Background & material design like (card) you can handle with simple CSS.